# Can ANSYS be installed and run on Amazon Workspace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, ansys

Seeing the great utility of the modernisation of computational resources, it would be great if computationally heavy software such as ansys could be installed on cloud workspace such as Amazon

Can ANSYS be installed and run on Amazon Workspace?

Comment: @Marcin Asking means if someone out there agrees to share. Had it been myself I would certainly welcome such question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a container -
https://optics.ansys.com/hc/en-us/articles/12325704816659-Dockerfile-support

If you can run Dockerd / Containerd in Amazon Workspace, you can also run containers with supported Ansys solvers.

A longer discussion of how to write a Dockerfile for Fluent on CentOS 7 -
https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/ansys/231493-ansys-installation-docker-container.html